# Shell Script Invocation Error with Xcode4 when trying to run a shell script as a build step

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

Here is what I get when I try to build my Xcode project:

```
Intermediates/demo2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/demo2.build/Script-5E564EAC1393823C00BFBA83.sh

/Users/ssbarnea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-fdzrmxojwtekcbeivraccjjadvqz/Build/Intermediates/demo2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/demo2.build/Script-5E564EAC1393823C00BFBA83.sh: line 2: ${PROJECT_DIR}/local-deploy.sh: No such file or directory
```

In Xcode I added to the default arget a new Build Phase, a "Run Script" that runs with shell `/bin/sh` and contains only:

```
'${PROJECT_DIR}/local-deploy.sh'
```

I can assure you that the local-deploy.sh file exists in the project directory and that it is executable. It even works if I call it from the console ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the following. s/'/"/g :-)

```
"${PROJECT_DIR}/local-deploy.sh"
```

- [Bourne Shell Tutorial - Strong versus weak quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-8)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that replacing this will work. You need just put **OpenCV.framework** folder in proper project folder and I think that is it. I tried out and it worked.